# Setting TabIndex at runtime based on criteria

Tags: c#, asp.net, tabindex

I've got an ASP.Net app with C# code-behind.  What we do is query a table based on a series of dropdownlists, and based on those choices there are 10 possible fields that might be displayed.  It's a little complicated, but for 2 separate instances, you might see these fields:

> txtEffDate 
>   txtePro 
>  
>   TBAccountNum 
>  
>   DDLBustype 
>  
>   chkEscalated

and then these fields:

> TBAccountNum 
>   txtClientID 
>   txtePro 
>   DDLBustype 
>   chkRework 
>   chkEscalated

It's all table driven so that logic is fine, I just wanted to give some background.

The problem is, when we're determining which controls to make visible the tab order goes wonky.  So I'm trying to set the tab index when I'm checking the controls.  I've got something like this:

```
if (reader.GetByte(0) == 1)
{
    txtEffDate.Visible = true;
    lblEffDate.Visible = true;
    txtEffDate.TabIndex = 9;
}
if (reader.GetByte(0) == 2)
{
    txtClientID.Visible = true;
    lblClientID.Visible = true;
    txtClientID.TabIndex = 7;
}
```

etc...  but the index isn't changing.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you explain what you are expecting a bit better? So you want to set the index of the dropdownlist selections on Select or...?

Comment: As I'm loading the page (Page_Load), I want to be able to set the index using C# code.  Basically, I want to know why ControlName.TabIndex = X isn't working.

Comment: Are you setting the tabIndex outside of the if statement again? Can you show us more of your code?